# EJB JPA CMT - Flush failure on large dataset

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jta

I've got a JBoss 6.3 EAP, JPA 2.0, EJB 3.1, CMT JTA web app.  DB is MSSQL2008R2, using MS JDBC driver, and hibernate 4.2.14 under the hood.

I've got a method that looks kind of like this, to duplicate a million Prices entities:

```
public void doStuff(Date newDate)
{
    List<Prices> prices = dao.getPrices(); //<< 1000000+ prices
    for (Prices price : prices)
    {
        Prices copy = price.clone();
        copy.setDate(newDate);
        entityManager.persist(copy);
        if (newDate.before(someDate))
        {
            price.setDate(someDate);
            entityManager.merge(price);
        }
    }
}
```

I set the JBoss EJB coordinator timeout to an hour, to let it run.  I increased heap size to -Xmx 3G after it ran out of memory the first time.

The code starts at 1:24am, it finishes at 1:36am, then at 2:24am, it fails with a transaction error, and rolls back.  The stacktrace says its during the flush.

```
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1510) [hibernate-e
ntitymanager-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]
```

I can see that if I break up the million into chunks of 10000 and flush after each, it doesn't even get near a million during the hour.  So flushing is clearly an expensive task.  But I suppose it starts flushing implicitly during JTA's post-intercept commit.

Should I just increase the timeout and try again?  It is a DEV database being used by a few others, and my code seems to lock the prices table, making it unqueryable from MSSQL SMSS, so it's not something I want to let run indefinitely.  But is this just an issue of needing more time?

Start of stacktrace:

```
02:24:45,157 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 in state  RUN
02:24:45,169 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
02:24:45,169 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 aborting with 1 threads active!
02:24:45,667 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 in state  CANCEL
02:24:46,209 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 in state  CANCEL_INTERRUPTED
02:24:46,210 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012120: TransactionReaper::check worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] not responding to interrupt when cancelling TX 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 -- worker marked as zombie and TX scheduled for mark-as-rollback
02:24:46,210 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012110: TransactionReaper::check successfuly marked TX 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:22 as rollback only
02:25:07,968 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
02:25:07,968 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
02:25:08,085 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff0a14021f:3d218bb8:56009132:24, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@2d633a18 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I rewrote it as SQL, and used 2 entityManager.createNativeQuery calls, instead of programmatic JPA, and it finished in 30 seconds or so.

So, the lesson is, don't bother with JPA for large data sets.  Work out the solution in SQL, and then grab the straight JDBC connection to do it.